# Add a Column to DataTable if Column is Empty

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

My datatable currently has 6 empty columns in between my last filled column and my added column.

May I know how can I check if a column is empty when adding my new column in?

```
if (!dtAll.Columns.Contains("Permissions"))
{
    dtAll.Columns.Add("Permissions");
}
```

Sample screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a column being empty? All of the row values for that column are null?

Comment: The entire columns are empty, with no values in all rows as well. I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick one liner to check if all the row values for a column "columnname" are null:

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().All(r => r.IsNull("columnname"));
```

IsNull may also optionally take an int column index or DataColumn type object

Bear in mind if you're importing from excel the the rows may not be null/dbnull - they might be empty strings, for example. you can still use this method by altering the test, perhaps like this:

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().All(r => r.Field<string>("columnname") == "");
```

Pause your code in the debugger and inspect a row value, work out how to test for Whatever value is in your column

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your column is empty using the following

```
bool isColumnEmpty = dtAll.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull("ColumnName")))
```